# Registry - NetworkList Profiles - cannot access through programs

Tags: c#, python, registry, vpn

When connecting to a new network, Windows asks if it is a home, work, or public network.

I use a VPN service, and on each connection, Windows displays that dialog like  . Problem is, the number is always one bigger, and I don't know why.

I thought I would check what is happening in registry, and found

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles
```

under which key all of them are stored along with others. Then I decided to write a program to check for them and remove before connecting again, so it would always make it  without the number, keeping registry from getting bloated. Simple enough, I made a 5 line Console program in C#, made it ask for admin, ran Visual Studio with admin privileges so it would allow me to access registry.
Code is:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine;
key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles");
foreach (string subkey in key.GetSubKeyNames())
     Console.WriteLine(subkey);
```

That was just to get the subkeys listed first, but even that did not work, as for some unknown reason, none were found, but no error messages either.

I looked up how to do it in Python too, which I only read about two days ago for the first time.

```
from _winreg import *
key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles', 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
for i in range(1024):
print EnumKey(key, i)
```

That code ends up printing no keys too, giving an Expected WindowsError when reaching the end.

I can of course see the subkeys having names like {numbersAndLettersSeparatedByDashes}, what are they called by the way? GUIDs? Or are those something else?
What I don't understand is that someone I sent the C# and Python codes, they worked on his Windows 7, x64 too, but C# only worked when it was a Windows Forms Solution. Not when console. Tested Python on another PC, same OS, but same result as on mine. Why? Is there a way to get this solved? Seems so strange for me, and I would be happy to get this done. Spent good hours on it getting nowhere. No errors and still failing.

I don't know if it's okay to post it like this for two languages, and Windows, but I do not know an other place where I could ask for help about this. Also sorry for the length but I believe it is necessary. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the `NetworkList` key with admin privileges, just change the `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` to `KEY_READ`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure whatever you are running to view the registry is not only running in administrator mode, but also is a 64-bit version.

Comment: It is low quality, please add more deatils.